# ¿Por qué no se ejecuta el script en el método?

Tags: c#, webforms

Tengo un método que llama a otros 2 métodos ya creados y 1 script, los métodos son el `stamper()`, `insert()`, `ScripManager()` pero si se ejecuta uno no se ejecuta el otro, es decir, el script no se ejecuta:

```
protected void printRegisterCot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {       
                InsertCot_Click();
                stamperPDF_Click();
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModalOk();", true);
                Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "10; url=recover.aspx");
            }
    private void stamperPDF_Click()....
    private void InsertCot_Click()....
```

Resultado de este:
Insertar en la base de datos: OK
crear el PDF con los datos: OK
mostrar scrip Modal: NO
redireccionar a recover.aspx: NO

```
protected void printRegisterCot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {       
                InsertCot_Click();
                //stamperPDF_Click();
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModalOk();", true);
                Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "10; url=recover.aspx");
            }
    private void stamperPDF_Click()....
    private void InsertCot_Click()....
```

Resultado de este:
Insertar en la base de datos: OK
crear el PDF con los datos: NO, deshabilitado
mostrar scrip Modal: OK
redireccionar a recover.aspx: NO

¿Por qué este comportamiento?

Answer (score 1):

Para redireccionar en webforms debes usar cualquiera de estas 2 formas.

```
Response.Redirect("recover.aspx");

Server.Transfer("recover.aspx");
```